# how the get the audience size in facebook using graph api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-marketing-api

i want to know how to get the size of audience in facebook graph api.
for example: how many people live in us, age between 20 and 30, and are interested in baseball.
i am having problems using the graph api, and python's request class.

i have this code for example

```
import requests

data2 = [
  ('type', 'adinterest'),
  ('q', 'baseball'),
  ('access_token', 'access code'),('limit','1000')
]

response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search', params=data2)
r=response.json()
```

Comment: What is your problem? Can you link to the documentation you followed?

Comment: i tried tons of codes and i can't get the audience size when i want more than 1 condition. the example i just wrote was 1 condition. how can i make it into more than 1?

i used these documentations:
ONE:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search 

TWO:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting
THREE:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs

Comment: (FYI, I would not have closed this as a duplicate, if you had anything new to show by now. But since you are presenting pretty much the same code as you did a week ago …)